# Can not insert own structure in standard vector but string can

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stdvector

I made simple structure:

```
struct sToken
{
    std::string token;
    unsigned int lineNb;
};
```

I want to insert this structure in standard vector using `push_back()` method, but when I do this:

```
std::vector<sToken> result;
result.push_back(tkn); //compiler-error
```

I get following error messages:
`no match for operator== in __first__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,_Container>::operator*<sToken*,std::vector<sToken> >()== in stl_algo.h`

But if I want to put standard string everything is OK:

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
result.push_back(tkn.token); //OK
```

I see that compiler is complaining about `operator==`, but why? Why should I provide `operator==` in this situation when I only want to put struct in vector? And if I must implement this operator, can you give me an idea how it should be implemented. Thanks.

Comment: How is `tkn` defined?

Comment: [The code works.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=35357ac8dd8f0c50c5664ddca64ebbf7-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) The error comes from something else.

Comment: The error look like it's from algorithm - are you sorting or searching that vector later?

Comment: +1 Your struct hasn't got anything fancy, it's a POD and shouldn't need an `operator=`.

Comment: most likely you are using `std:find` somewhere or making a `==` comparation without overloading the `operator==` on your struct

Comment: tkn is defined in for loop: `for(sToken &tkn : *t)`. But I also tried to create sToken separately just before adding in vector, but without success.

Comment: yes, I'm using find before pushing element in next way:
`if(std::find(result.begin(), result.end(), tkn.token) == result.end()) {
                    result.push_back(tkn);
                }`

Comment: ok..I commented find and don't getting error messages any more..I just need to think now where I'm wrong. Thanks a lot for so speedy help. I would spend much much more time on searching problem.

Comment: result is declared as sToken..here is problem I believe

Comment: -1: You failed to produce a testcase that demonstrates the problem. That is, your question is fundamentally broken and does not exhibit a workable question.

Comment: yes, but guys found out source of problem which is find function. I tried to make question as much better I could but is hard to make it when you don't know source of problem, and pasting whole code is not solution.

Comment: I guess he failed simply because he didn't understand the problem. sometimes i think people on s.o are more interested in the question contributing to the site than educating/helping askers

Comment: @ViniyoShouta But if you think that you cannot insert an object of a user defined type into a vector, then you should test for that *only*, not test code with 100 other things going on.

Comment: @legends2k It doesn’t. OP failed to post the relevant code.

Comment: @chao if you don't know the source of the problem, it's more helpful to narrow it down until you _do_, than to select a possible culprit at random and post it with no context

Comment: If you think a proper question is so important suggest/do an edit to it. **I think** you are failing to see the point of a person who doesn't understand at all since you understand.

Comment: @juanchopanza, can't agree with you, because i didn't know that find function can cause me that problem, so that leads me on wrong path. anyway, thanks everybody for time and suggestions, especially Viniyo Shouta. now we can try to help other people :)

Comment: @ViniyoShouta I think that if I believe a problem to be somewhere, I test for that and only that. If it turns out the problem isn't there, I look somewhere else. It really is quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you're using std::find, you need to overload the operator == on your struct

```
struct sToken
{
    std::string token;
    unsigned int lineNb;
    bool operator ==(const sToken& ref )
    {
        return ref.token.compare( this->token ) == 0;
    }
};
```

In this example, `token` will be used to differ(indentify) this struct from others. You can of course change it to whatever you want

## edit

if you want to use `std::find` looking for the `std::string` `tkn.token`  as your comment says then you need to overload it like this:

```
bool operator ==(const std::string ctoken)
{
    return ctoken.compare( this->token ) == 0;
}
```

You have to do this because `std::find` will compare the vector members with your `sToken` object.

Comment: great. I tried your solution and works like a charm. The problem was really find function, and operator== fixes problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> #### C++11, 25.2.5 Find

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value);
```

> 1    The first iterator i in the range [first,last) for which the following corresponding conditions hold: ***i == value**, [...]. Returns last if no such iterator is found.

This indicates that find will use *operator==* to *find* the desired element.
You'll need to implement `operator==()` for your class/struct like this:

```
struct sToken
{
    std::string token;
    unsigned int lineNb;
    bool operator== (sToken const & rhs) 
    { 
      return !token.compare(rhs.token) && (lineNb == rhs.lineNb); 
    }
};
```

or like this:

```
struct sToken
{
    std::string token;
    unsigned int lineNb;
};
bool operator== (sToken const & lhs, sToken const & rhs) 
{ 
  return !lhs.token.compare(rhs.token) && (lhs.lineNb == rhs.lineNb); 
}
```

This compares the whole struct to be equal. If you only want specific member to match each other: Adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi chao you need to overload **operator ==**. Here is the my version of code that works quite fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct sToken
{
    std::string token;
    unsigned int lineNb;

    bool operator == (const sToken& obj)
    {
        if(token.compare(obj.token) != 0)
            return false;

        if(lineNb != obj.lineNb)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct sToken a1;
    a1.token = "jksdhfjksdf";
    a1.lineNb = 5;

    struct sToken a2;
    a2.token = "jksdhfjksdf";
    a2.lineNb = 5;

    if(a1 == a2)
        cout<< "jhfdhvhjdf"<<endl;

    vector<sToken> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(a1);
    myVector.push_back(a2);

    cout<<myVector.size();

    return 0;
}
```